# JsonReaderException quando realiza JObject.Parse

Tags: c#

Quando executo `JObject.Parse` inicia uma exception contento:

> Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.

O Json que estou tentando interpretar seria:

```
[{
  "modid": "ExtraFood",
  "name": "Extra Food",
  "version": "1.7.10-0.7.45",
  "mcversion": "1.7.10",
  "description": "Extra Food by mincrmatt12 and dmf444. This mod will extend the amount of food that is in minecraft. We don't want you to starve yet, and we've added new midgame-lategame content.",
  "credits": "Dmf444, Mincrmatt12 and thanks to all those who helped on IRC and MCForge Forums",
  "logoFile": "assets/extrafood/EFlogo.png",
  "url": "https://github.com/TeamDmfMM/Extra-Food",
  "updateUrl": "",
  "authorList": ["mincrmatt12", "dmf444"],
  "parent": "",
  "screenshots": [],
  "dependencies": ["mod_MinecraftForge"]
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que usar o JArray.

```
JArray v = JArray.Parse(s);
```

Com ele vai pega um json q é uma coleção.

Pode pegar o item assim:

```
var item = v[0]["modid"].ToString();
```

E assim vai.

Ou tenra tirar os [ ] do início e final

Comment: e no caso do `authorList`, o mesmo ocorre em `dependencies`